# How to insert an image in an imagebox through path on a server

Tags: excel, vba, image

Hi I'm using thus code to load an image into an image box:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, fname As String
Dim p As Object


'~~> Adding a temp sheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

'~~> Insert the picture in the newly created worksheet
fname = "\\IPADDRESS\folder\fototest\image.jpg"
SavePicture img.Picture, fname
DoEvents
Set p = ws.Pictures.Insert(fname)
```

the problem is that the image is located on a server that I reach through IP address and excel crashes because it can't reach the address.
How can I fix?

Comment: When you try accessing the path ``\\IPADDRESS\folder\fototest\`` in your PC, through the windows file browser, are you successful? Can you create a file there manually?

Comment: @KobyDouek no I can't access the path either through the file browser

Comment: Then there's your problem right there. It's a permissions issue.

Comment: I was leaning towards an improperly formatted path, but yes, make it work in File Explorer first!

Answer (score 0):

Your VBA crashes because of lack of permissions to the target directory. In order to use your `SavePicture` procedure, first you need `read write execute` permissions in the remote target directory, and to make sure you have access to this server if it's in a different domain.

Comment: How can I get the permissions to the folder?

Comment: @FrancescoBordignon You need to ask an administrator or the folder owner to grant your user full permissions.

Comment: Why would he need `write` and `execute` permission? Just `read` would be fine. How do you know it's a permission issue in the first place?

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers He's trying to **save** an image to this folder.

Comment: Fair enough! I thought he was loading it into the WB from the location, not saving it to the locaton